# Ordered and grouped gantt chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create an ordered and grouped gantt chart, where by `gantt1.dat$Common.name` is what I am depicting through time, `gantt1.dat$Animal.group` is my grouping variable, and `gantt1.dat$time` is what my ordering is based on.

```
# This is my data

gantt1.dat <- structure(list(Common.name = structure(c(59L, 11L, 20L, 23L, 
31L, 43L, 56L, 71L, 7L, 30L, 52L, 21L, 35L, 37L, 16L, 15L, 22L, 
4L, 39L, 13L, 57L, 12L, 68L, 34L, 61L, 63L, 70L, 3L, 55L, 47L, 
54L, 24L, 62L, 40L, 26L, 33L, 27L, 50L, 14L, 58L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 
6L, 9L, 10L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 25L, 28L, 29L, 32L, 36L, 38L, 41L, 
42L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 48L, 49L, 51L, 53L, 60L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
69L, 72L, 73L, 8L), .Label = c("American black bear ", "Belding's ground squirrel", 
"Black-tailed prairie dog", "Black rat", "Botta's pocket gopher", 
"Brandt's vole", "Brown rat", "Brown treesnake", "Califorian vole", 
"California ground squirrel", "Canada goose", "Cat", "Common brushtail possum", 
"Common vole", "Dingo", "Dog", "Eastern deer mouse", "Ethiopian wolf", 
"European hedgehog", "European herring gull", "European rabbit", 
"Feral pig", "Feral pigeon", "Ferret", "Geomyidae spp.", "Greater bandicoot rat", 
"Gunnison's prairie dog", "Hairy-footed gerbil", "Himalayan field rat", 
"House mouse", "House sparrow", "Indian bush rat", "Indian crested porcupine", 
"Indian desert gerbil", "Indian gerbil", "Jungle palm squirrel", 
"Lesser bandicoot rat", "Lesser ricefield rat", "Little indian field mouse", 
"Malayan field rat", "Mazama pocket gopher", "Middle east blind mole-rat", 
"Monk parakeet", "Montane vole", "Mountain beaver", "Mountain pocket gopher", 
"Mus spp.", "Muskrat", "Mustela spp.", "Northern pocket gopher", 
"Plains pocket gophers", "Polynesian rat", "Raccoon", "Rattus spp.", 
"Red-necked wallaby", "Red-winged blackbird", "Red fox", "Ricefield rat", 
"Rook", "Sand-colored soft-furred rat", "Short-tailed bandicoot rat", 
"Soft-furred rat", "Stoat", "Tammar wallaby", "Tasmanian pademelon", 
"Thomomys spp.", "unspecified rodent spp.", "Unspecified rodent spp.", 
"Utah prairie dog", "Weasel", "Western jackdaw", "White-tailed prairie dog", 
"Wolf"), class = "factor"), Animal.group = c("Bird", "Bird", 
"Bird", "Bird", "Bird", "Bird", "Bird", "Bird", "Mammal", "Mammal", 
"Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", 
"Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", 
"Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", 
"Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", 
"Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", 
"Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", 
"Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", 
"Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", 
"Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Mammal", "Reptile"
), min = c(1961L, 2007L, 1999L, 1961L, 1961L, 2008L, 2002L, 1961L, 
1974L, 1974L, 1974L, 1983L, 1983L, 1985L, 1986L, 1986L, 1989L, 
1995L, 1985L, 1996L, 1996L, 1997L, 1992L, 1983L, 1998L, 1999L, 
1999L, 1998L, 2001L, 1999L, 1999L, 1996L, 1997L, 1999L, 1999L, 
2008L, 2014L, 1995L, 2007L, 2006L, 1999L, 2019L, 1999L, 2010L, 
2000L, 2007L, 2014L, 2016L, 2020L, 2002L, 1983L, 2000L, 2010L, 
1997L, 2006L, 1995L, 1998L, 2000L, 2009L, 1999L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2002L, 2013L, 1983L, 2011L, 2001L, 2017L, 2011L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2013L, 2001L), max = c(2008, 2007.1, 1999.1, 1961.1, 1961.1, 
2008.1, 2002.1, 1961.1, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2019, 2018, 2020, 2010, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2015, 2005, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2017, 2020, 2016, 2016, 2009, 2010, 2008, 2006, 2013, 2017, 
1998, 2009, 2007, 1999.1, 2019.1, 1999.1, 2010.1, 2000.1, 2007.1, 
2014.1, 2016.1, 2020.1, 2002.1, 1983.1, 2000.1, 2010.1, 1997.1, 
2006.1, 1995.1, 1998.1, 2000.1, 2009.1, 1999.1, 2002.1, 2003.1, 
2002.1, 2013.1, 1983.1, 2011.1, 2001.1, 2017.1, 2011.1, 2017.1, 
2017.1, 2013.1, 2020), time = c(47, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 
0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 
0.0999999999999091, 46, 46, 46, 37, 37, 35, 34, 33, 29, 25, 25, 
24, 24, 23, 23, 22, 22, 21, 21, 19, 19, 17, 17, 13, 13, 9, 7, 
5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 
0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 
0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 
0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 
0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 
0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 
0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 
0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 0.0999999999999091, 
0.0999999999999091, 19)), row.names = c(NA, -73L), groups = structure(list(
    Common.name = structure(1:73, .Label = c("American black bear ", 
    "Belding's ground squirrel", "Black-tailed prairie dog", 
    "Black rat", "Botta's pocket gopher", "Brandt's vole", "Brown rat", 
    "Brown treesnake", "Califorian vole", "California ground squirrel", 
    "Canada goose", "Cat", "Common brushtail possum", "Common vole", 
    "Dingo", "Dog", "Eastern deer mouse", "Ethiopian wolf", "European hedgehog", 
    "European herring gull", "European rabbit", "Feral pig", 
    "Feral pigeon", "Ferret", "Geomyidae spp.", "Greater bandicoot rat", 
    "Gunnison's prairie dog", "Hairy-footed gerbil", "Himalayan field rat", 
    "House mouse", "House sparrow", "Indian bush rat", "Indian crested porcupine", 
    "Indian desert gerbil", "Indian gerbil", "Jungle palm squirrel", 
    "Lesser bandicoot rat", "Lesser ricefield rat", "Little indian field mouse", 
    "Malayan field rat", "Mazama pocket gopher", "Middle east blind mole-rat", 
    "Monk parakeet", "Montane vole", "Mountain beaver", "Mountain pocket gopher", 
    "Mus spp.", "Muskrat", "Mustela spp.", "Northern pocket gopher", 
    "Plains pocket gophers", "Polynesian rat", "Raccoon", "Rattus spp.", 
    "Red-necked wallaby", "Red-winged blackbird", "Red fox", 
    "Ricefield rat", "Rook", "Sand-colored soft-furred rat", 
    "Short-tailed bandicoot rat", "Soft-furred rat", "Stoat", 
    "Tammar wallaby", "Tasmanian pademelon", "Thomomys spp.", 
    "unspecified rodent spp.", "Unspecified rodent spp.", "Utah prairie dog", 
    "Weasel", "Western jackdaw", "White-tailed prairie dog", 
    "Wolf"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(41L, 42L, 
        28L, 18L, 43L, 44L, 9L, 73L, 45L, 46L, 2L, 22L, 20L, 
        39L, 16L, 15L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 3L, 12L, 17L, 4L, 32L, 
        50L, 35L, 37L, 51L, 52L, 10L, 5L, 53L, 36L, 24L, 13L, 
        54L, 14L, 55L, 19L, 34L, 56L, 57L, 6L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 
        30L, 61L, 62L, 38L, 63L, 11L, 64L, 31L, 29L, 7L, 21L, 
        40L, 1L, 65L, 25L, 33L, 26L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 23L, 
        70L, 27L, 8L, 71L, 72L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 73L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# This is my gantt chart code
qplot(ymin = min,
                ymax = max,
                x = Common.name,
                colour = Animal.group,
                geom = "linerange",
                data = gantt1.dat,
                size = I(4)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1960, 1965, 1970, 1975, 1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020), 
                     labels = c("1960s", "", "1970s", "", "1980s", "", "1990s", "", "2000s", "", "2010s", "", "2020s")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  labs(y="Year of publication", x = "", colour="Class")
```

The above code produces this gantt chart
[image: gantt chart]

I can achieve my desired gantt chart by manually re-ordering the levels of `gantt1.dat$Common.name` so that they plot in the order that I am after, however **there must be an easier way to do this?** Re-ordering lots of factor levels in a specific order is time consuming and inefficient. In the below gantt chart you can see that the species are grouped by `gantt1.dat$Animal.group`, and then species are ordered by the time period within groups, such that birds/mammals/reptiles with the longest time period appear closer to the bottom of the chart.

[image: Desired gantt chart]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

````
qplot(ymin = min,
      ymax = max,
      x = reorder(Common.name,-min),
      colour = Animal.group,
      geom = "linerange",
      data = gantt1.dat,
      size = I(4)) +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1960, 1965, 1970, 1975, 1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020), 
                       labels = c("1960s", "", "1970s", "", "1980s", "", "1990s", "", "2000s", "", "2010s", "", "2020s")) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
          legend.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
    labs(y="Year of publication", x = "", colour="Class")```
````

[image]